# How to transfer tensorflow.TensorProto to custom xxx.TensorProto?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I define a custom xxx.TensorProto which has the same struct as tensorflow.TensorProto. I use tf.make_tensor_proto to transfer a ndarray to tensorflow.TensorProto, but when I try to write tensorflow.TensorProto to xxx.TensorProto, it always fail.

proto file:

```
package xxx;
message Tensor {
  string name = 1;     
  TensorProto tensor_proto = 2;
}
```

e.g.,

```
val = numpy.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
xxxtp = xxx.Tensor()
xxxtp.tensor_proto  = tf.make_tensor_proto(val)
```

This result in :
`AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to field "tensor_proto" in protocol message object.`

While I use `xxxtp.tensor_proto.CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(val))`, it result in: `TypeError: Parameter to CopyFrom() must be instance of same class: expected xxx.TensorProto got tensorflow.TensorProto.`

A possible way is to split each item in the xxx.TensorProto to assign the value.

e.g.,

```
tp = tf.make_tensor_proto(val)
xxxtp.tensor_proto.dtype = tp.dtype
....
```

Comment: You appear to answer your own question. You cannot assign one Protobuf Message to another unless they are the same (same package, same Message). If your `xxx.TensorProto` is the same as `tensorflow.Proto`, why do you need to recreate it? You may want to consider using the original Message (type). The solution will be to write the Python code to create a `xxx.TensorProto` from scratch and assign each field manually from `tensorflow.TensorProto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xxxtp.tensor_proto.ParseFromString(tp.SerializeToString())
```

Serialize to string then parse back.